# Draw qualified sample from dataframe

Tags: r

I'd like to draw a random sample of rows from a dataframe; however, not all rows should be included in the draw, just those fulfilling a negative condition: that they do not match a certain variable in a second dataframe.
Here's some mock data:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(
  x = c("A", "B", "L", "G", "C", "F", "S", "J", "G", "K", "X", "Y", "B", "C", "Z")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  a = LETTERS[1:5],
  b = 1:5
)
```

The dataframe I wish to draw the sample from is df1. The draw should exclude those data points in df1$x that match the data points in the first column of `df2`, which is `df2$a`. So far I've tried this:

```
df1[sample(1:nrow(df2[-(match(df1$x, df2$a))]), 7, replace = F), ]
```

which gives an error message; and I've tried this:

```
df1[sample(1:nrow(df2[!match(df1$x, df2$a),]), 7, replace = F), ]
```

which does not give an error but does contain unwanted data. Any solutions?

Comment: Try this `df1[sample(which(is.na(match(df1$x, df2$a))), 7, replace = FALSE),,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Okay, that's helpful too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can exclude the rows by taking indices in `df1$x` which are not present in `df2$a` using `which` and then take `sample` from those indices.

```
df1[sample(which(!df1$x %in% df2$a), 7), ,drop = FALSE]

#   x
#7  S
#15 Z
#8  J
#9  G
#3  L
#12 Y
#6  F
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a question: what exactly does `drop = F` do?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann since you have only one column in `df1`, `drop = F` ensures that it returns a dataframe. Remove that parameter and it returns a vector.

Comment: Cool! Thanks again.